# Оператор присваивание ведет себя неожиданно

Tags: c++

Почему не происходит ошибка компиляции при преобразовании `const A&` к `const int&` в операторе присваивание:

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A& operator=(const A& param)
    {
        cout << "operator=\n";
        x = param.x;
        return *this;
    }
    operator int&()
    {
        cout << "operator()\n";
        return x;
    }
    A(const int& param)
    {
        x = param;
    }
    void putX()
    {
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a(999);
    a = a + 33;
    a.putX();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а вы перегрузили оператор присваивания?

Comment: @Yuriy Orlov Да, в коде но есть

Comment: Но проблема не в этом. Ваш код кстати успешно компилируется и выполняется https://ideone.com/FCtuPn

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код можно переписать следующим образом, чтобы было понятно, что происходит:

```
a = A(static_cast<int>(a) + 33);
```

Всё это происходит неявно. Чтобы получить ошибку компиляции, сделайте конструктор `explicit`, это запретит неявное создание `A` из `int`

Comment: Как может происходить преобразование A из int? Я ведь не сделал так:  A& operator=(const A& int);

Comment: @Тарас, у Вас есть конструктор A, который имеет один аргумент  — int. Поэтому происходит создание этого объекта. Компилятор всегда пытается сделать код рабочим, в рамках правил, конечно.

Comment: @Тарас Все из-за неявного приведения типов: результатом выполнения операции `a + 33` является `int`, т.к. у вас не перегружен `operator +`, который принимал бы такие параметры в качестве аргументов (т.е. `int` и `A`), то переменная `a` неявно приводится к `int`, т.к.  у вас существует оператор приведение к `int` (`operator int&()`), а затем этот результат неявно приводится к классу `A` за счет соответствующего конструктора `A(const int& param)` из-за того, что вы пытаетесь присвоить результат вычисления экземпляру данного класса